# Dispatching an Action in a Timer, but it executes right away

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just want to create a timer for a property of an object, and have it execute after the timer goes off, but instead it dispatches right away.  Am I missing something?  How can I get around this?  I thought it would be something I could easily Google, but I surprisingly didn't find anything

```
// example page object
pageObj: {
    id: someId,
    name: somePageName,
    timer: someTimerObj,
    //etc..
}

export const someFunc = () => ( dispatch ) => {
    let timerObj = setTimeout( () => dispatch( _getNextAction( someInfo ), 5000 ));  // this keeps getting executed right away when i just want it to execute when the timer goes off in 5 seconds
    dispatch( setPageProperty( pageObj.id, 'timer', timerObj ));
}

const _getNextAction = ( someInfo ) => ( dispatch ) => {
    if ( someInfo ) {
        dispatch( pageIn );
    }
    else {
        dispatch( pageOut );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced a closing parentheses.

You have written

```
setTimeout( () => dispatch( _getNextAction( someInfo ), 5000 ));
```

When it should be

```
setTimeout(() => dispatch( _getNextAction( someInfo )), 5000);
```

I believe since you aren't providing an explicit timeout value (since `5000` is being passed into `dispatch` instead of `setTimeout`), it's taking that to mean a timeout of `0` and triggering the callback immediately.

Comment: ahhhh  ok let me try .  darnit!